# What kind of body do ghosts have?

Tags: body, ghosts

Did the ancient rishis comment anything about the kind of body ghosts  have? And please don't say that ghosts do not have any bodies. People from all over the world have reported seeing their dead relatives as having the same human like features (the appearance they had while they were alive).

On top of that, they are seen in clothes. (The clothes they wore before their death).

So what exactly is this ghostly body called in sanskrit, that not only mimicks the appearance and features of it's former flesh body but could also create out of thin air, the garments that it normally rejects after death.

Thnx.

Comment: Have you seen your own body in your dreams?

Comment: Ghost is a very very very broad term as per Vedic metaphysics. Its called Sukshma Sharira, and yet there are other bodies beyond that of a general "ghost".

Comment: @Arkaprabha Majumdar , pl don't mix up Sukshma Sharira with ghost. Bcoz everybody has physical as well as intangible body (Sukshma Sharira). But everybody is not a ghost :D Ghost is a form of unfulfilled desires (waasana). They call it भूत योनी, प्रेत योनी.

Comment: No no I am not synonymizing ghosts with sukhshma sharira. I am just saying that ghost is a very broad term with respect to what Vedic metaphysics has to say about this

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar, So you mean to say that after the death of gross body,  some of us (as ghosts) remain in subtle bodies?

Comment: Some of us remain in subtle bodies, others due to bad karma remain as pretas, or pishachas wherein their subtle desires are manifested as bodies which do not permit them to go to higher lokas. For each loka the physicality is relative, so for them their desire-made-body is physical in their loka, whereas the gross body is physical in our loka. So as pretas and pishachas, they wander for some time and when their time is over, you'll find no trace of them.

Comment: @Vineet, Unfullfilled desires, bind us to the cycle of reincarnation (coming and going). Unfullfilled desires (like the desire to buy a car which wasn't fullfilled while being alive) won't make us ghosts ...It's actually, when people after death can't let go of their attachments (clings on to their possessions & loved ones) they become ghosts. Violent unnantural deaths also makes us ghosts, including negative karma, as Arkaprabha says above. Evil deeds like practicing witchcraft, and so on (as told by Krishna in Gita).

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse Excuse me but witchcraft doesn't necessarily lead to being ghosts. Krishna has only said worshipping spirits does. That doesn't mean witchcraft necessarily. Only Abrahamics say such stuff.

Comment: User 9072 aka Arkaprabha could have elaborated on this point further. Unfortunately, he left HSE. He was a practitioner of witchcraft and simultaneously a Ram Bhakta.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury, Prabhupada in his Gita commentary said that witchcraft, black arts etc. comes under ghost worshipping coz people who practice such arts, deal with malevolent entities like demons or evil spirits. Sometimes these entities are worshipped in order to gain supernatural powers. This happens not just in western satanic cults but also in hinduism (the tantrics). But lets not deviate from the main topic ... People after death (as believed by many hindus) remain close to their family members for the first few days until pinda. I think they remain in their subtle bodies.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury, ..... Woah.... Is that for real bro? ... He was into witchcraft? ... What makes you say such a thing?

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse Witchcraft doesn't always involve ghosts. It's a common misconception. A witch may or may not work with such entities. It's not mandatory. Anyway, I know he was into witchcraft because I know him personally. He's a close friend of mine.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Witchcraft is real? I thought it was fake! Is it a bad thing to do?

Comment: IMO, it's not a bad thing to do. It can be very useful in many instances, such as curing people. @Shashwat